# Is it possible to read Evernote content without having to authenticate?

Tags: evernote

What is the easiest, lowest-friction method to read a note programmatically in Evernote?  Given that you can share notes by simply generating a unique URL to them, I find it curious that you can't do this programatically as well.

Put another way, I can read notes from my browser without having to authenticate to Evernote. Can I do this programmatically as well?  If I have a URL with GUID, can I use this to request the note via code and read it that way?

I attempted to do this -- to use the "Share" URL to read the note. It didn't work, for some reason. When requested programmtically, I was getting 404s for some reason, which makes me think Evernote has some safeguards against using it in this method.

Is there a way to do this -- to read note content via some service without having to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you can. You just need to use the getNote method with an empty string as the first argument (auth token).